# I need your help for usage of "on"

Tags: prepositions

Here is a sentence,

"His father and other people worked on spaceships."

I wanna know why "on" was used.

And can I use "at" instead of "on"?

If it can't, please tell me why.

My expressions might be odd because I'm non-english speaker.

Thank you.

Comment: Think of a ship (the water kind). You can be on it. You can be in it. You can’t be ‘at’ it.

Comment: It's the same with other types of work: "His father was working on gravitation theory." OTOH "His father was working ***at*** NASA."

Answer (score 1):

You would usually use *on* if what follows is the topic

> I am working on the Riemann hypothesis

Either *at* or *on* work if followed by a verbal form

> I am working at proving the Riemann hypothesis
> I am working on proving the Riemann hypothesis

For places you choose what is appropriate for the characteristics of the place and this may not be either *on* or *at*.

> I am working on the roof
> I am working on an ocean liner
> I am working in the White House
> I am working at home
> I am working at Walmart
> I am working under the floor

Answer (score 0):

Let me change your example a bit to better illustrate the difference:

> Joseph worked **on** the stadium.

This means that *Joseph was working to build or maintain the stadium itself*.

> Joseph worked **at** the stadium.

This means that Joseph had a job *located at* the stadium, but we don't know what kind; he could be a groundskeeper, a concession worker, an office manager, or maybe even the coach for the sports team that plays there.

The distinction between *on* and *at* is clear here because you normally talk about people being *in* a stadium, not *on* a stadium.

Your example, though, is less clear:

> Mary worked on spaceships.

This could mean that *Mary built or maintained spaceships*, or it could mean that *Mary had a job on board spaceships*; this sentence, as written, doesn't clarify.

You'd expect this to be made clear by the surrounding context, or by the following sentences, but in some cases you might be able to tell the difference when spoken aloud, with a very subtle change in cadence/emphasis:

> Mary (*worked on*) spaceships.

vs

> Mary worked (*on spaceships*).